# What does the compiler generate when we program switch table in C language?

Tags: c, switch-statement, bootloader

I am quite interested in compiler inner workings. I came across an article that it is not safe to use switch tables in boot mode since the switch table generate lookup tables located in flash. In boot mode since the flash is not initialised this can lead to problem.

Can any one explain what is the code generated by compiler on using switch table and where the code is located?

Comment: The compiler is free to generate whatever code it wants to to support a switch statement.  If there are only a very few cases, it might implement it as an if/else sequence.  If the case values form a reasonably dense sequence, it may use a direct lookup table.  If there are lots of sparse cases, it could use a hash table.  You have to assume that any of these are possible.

Comment: I guess that `-S` compiler flag could help you in checking it by yourself.

Comment: If you're interested in how compilers work, then you have two ways to learn: One is to check what machine code a compiler actually generates in certain situations, which can be found out by using *disassemblers*. The other way is simply to try and make your own compiler. C is actually a relatively simple language, and it's easy to make a parser for plain C. There are many tutorials and good books available, and it's also great fun to make your own compiler. It doesn't have to generate executable machine code. IMO this is the best way to learn what goes on in a compiler.

Comment: The first premise is possibly wrong. At least many earlier CPUs run code initially directly from EEPROM/ROM/Flash, which the memory controller (or the lack of it) placed at the far end of physical memory space.